# full page background in css not appearing

Tags: css, background-image

For some reason my full page background in css is not working. I did this once before and it worked great, but now I get nothing but a white background. This is a section of my relevant css code:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

/* render html5 elements as block */
header, footer, section, aside, nav, article {
display: block;
}

html {
    line-height: 1;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url(file:///HD/Users/Barbra/Sites/HSMAI/images/vbcc_background.jpg) no-repeat center center     fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
- moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

/* layout */

#wrapper {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #86D1C7 5%, #A8BCFA 53%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #86D1C7 5%, #A8BCFA 53%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #86D1C7 5%, #A8BCFA 53%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #86D1C7 5%, #A8BCFA 53%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #86D1C7 5%, #A8BCFA 53%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0.05, #86D1C7),
color-stop(0.53, #A8BCFA)
);
border: 2px solid #333;
/* curved border radius */
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I am certain all files are in the proper place and all links are specified correctly.

Comment: Are you running a local webserver?

Comment: `background-image: url(file:///HD/Users/Barbra/Sites/HSMAI/images/vbcc_background.jpg) no-repeat center center     fixed;` points to a local file

Comment: Try background-image on body not on html. Checo the correct path AMD file name (case sensitive). You have written `- moz-background-size` (space after `-`). Typo?

Answer (score 1):

The value for `background-image` is **only the URL to the image**.
If you put any other value, the declaration is invalid.

Change:

```
background-image: url(file:///HD/Users/Barbra/Sites/HSMAI/images/vbcc_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

to

```
background-image: url(file:///HD/Users/Barbra/Sites/HSMAI/images/vbcc_background.jpg)
```

or

```
background: url(file:///HD/Users/Barbra/Sites/HSMAI/images/vbcc_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly. A code block is inserted by indenting 4 spaces before any line of code. I've formatted the code for you this time, but please format it properly next time. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 0):

Give the background to the body element and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url(file:///HD/Users/Barbra/Sites/HSMAI/images/vbcc_background.jpg) no-repeat center center     fixed;
```

should be

```
background: url('///HD/Users/Barbra/Sites/HSMAI/images/vbcc_background.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
```